# Umbraco - ContentTypeService failed to find a content type with alias - page, controls, media disappeared

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

What have I not done here? I logged back on to my Umbraco site and my items are not in the content tree.

Using Web Matrix I created a new Umbraco website.

I created a new DataType FavouriteCoffees.

I created a new DocumentType FavouriteCoffees.

I changed Landing Page to allow FavouriteCoffees under it.

I uploaded a JPG to the Media folder.

I created a new Landing Page item using it.

I previewed it, saved and published it.

I closed the browser and Web Matrix. I re-opened Web Matrix and browsed to the website (http://localhost:64743/) and got a YSOD:

```
ContentTypeService failed to find a content type with alias "FavouriteCoffees".
```

I logged into Umbraco and none of the above are present - no DataType, DocumentType etc.

Inside the website folder I can see my JPG (C:\Umbraco\Umbraco CMS3\Media\1050)

Comment: Try not having the same alias for your data- and documenttype?

Comment: Document types use lowerCamelCase, ensure when using the `ContentService` you reference the alias `favouriteCoffees`.

Regarding the data disappearing, are you using SQL server or Embedded? If you create the content again and restart does it disappear? have you done an upgrade? Does the application have read/write permissions to the App_Data folder?

If all else fails, check the logs.

Comment: Jannik Anker that won't make any difference at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue of using Web Matrix with SQL Server CE.

[Link to Umbraco forums](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-4621)

SQL Server CE will hold the information for ten seconds, and then write to the database. If anything "bad" happens in that time to or if you close/restart Web Matrix it is possible that the data will not be written to the DB.

This explains why the problem for me was intermittent.

I've only found this today because my Media folder had items but they were not selectable in my new page. Upon clicking on them in Media I got a 404. A search turned this link up.

The fix is to download Microsoft SQL Server Express and use that instead (or the full blown SQL Server if you have it).